# Why is System.Web.Routing added in "compilation" section in default MVC3 project web.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

When I create a new project using "ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application" template in Visual Studio 2010 I get a project with web.config that among other stuff has this in `<system.web><compilation><assemblies>`

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0,
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Now this section controls the list of assemblies that are referenced during ASP.NET precompilation - the process that turns .aspx, .ascx and .cshtml files into .NET assemblies.

Those files are used for "views" and typically contain code for displaying web page elements. I've carefully looked through the contents of `System.Web.Routing` namespace and I can't find anything there that would be useful in a "view".

What's the purpose of referencing `System.Web.Routing` in `<compilation>` section of web.config?

Comment: if you remove those assebmly you will get a compiler error. because all Controller will look for RouteData values as soon as they requested.

Comment: @Ravi: How often do you have controllers in .aspx files?

Comment: i never use aspx for mvc.  i use razor. actually why you are interested in this route dll.  it's needed to get the routedata values for views.

Comment: @Ravi: Great, how many controllers do you have in your Razor views? I'm interested because I don't get why it is referenced in `compilation` section which is what I say in my question.